# Interpolation of an array of points

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following data points that represent the boundaries of a constellation.

```js
let boundaries = [
    {
      ra: 344.46530375,
      dec: 35.1682358
    },
    {
      ra: 344.34285125,
      dec: 53.1680298
    },
    {
      ra: 351.45289375,
      dec: 53.1870041
    },
    ...
]
```

Irrelevant, but these have been extracted from IAU quoted values.

However. Between each of these points I need what is known as the "great circle distance" - or the orthodromic distance, between point `i` and point `i+1`. To do that, we can interpolate between point `i` and point `i+1` at a given precision, `x`.

I have written the following function which can perform this operation (it's worth noting that is done in Equatorial Coordinates - **not** Cartesian - so the Mathematics is slightly more complex, but not massively so).

The function for interpolate between two points is as follows (written in Typescript ES6 for prosperity and safety):

```js
/**
 * getInterpolatedEquatorialCoordinates()
 *
 * @description This function takes in a start and end
 * @param start EquatorialCoordinate
 * @param end EquatorialCoordinate
 * @param precision number
 * @output returns the interpolated array of []EquatorialCoordinate points:
 */
export const getInterpolatedEquatorialCoordinates = (
  start: EquatorialCoordinate,
  end: EquatorialCoordinate,
  precision: number
): Array<EquatorialCoordinate> => {
  // The interpolated points array to return:
  const points: Array<EquatorialCoordinate> = []

  // Obtain the difference between the end coordinate's Right Ascension, RA, and the start coordinate's RA:
  let nra = ((end.ra - start.ra)) % 360

  if (nra > 180) nra = nra - 360
  if (nra < -180) nra = nra + 360

  // Obtain the "gradient" rate of change of RA:
  const dra: number = nra / precision

  // Obtain the difference between the end coordinate's Declination, dec, and the start coordinate's dec:
  const ndec = ((end.dec - start.dec))

  // Obtain the "gradient" rate of change of dec:
  const ddec: number = ndec / precision

  let i = 0

  // Obtain the interpolated EquatorialCoordinate points for each step:
  while (i < precision) {
    i++
    points.push({
      ra: start.ra + (dra * i),
      dec: start.dec + (ddec * i)
    })
  }

  return points
}
```

I have run this through a test suit, between the first two points of the above `boundaries`, to obtain it's validity Mathematically:

```js
test('getInterpolatedEquatorialCoordinates', function () {
  const start = {
    ra: 344.46530375,
    dec: 35.1682358
  }

  const end = {
    ra: 344.34285125,
    dec: 53.1680298
  }

  const minRA = Math.min(start.ra, end.ra)
  const minDec = Math.min(start.dec, end.dec)

  const maxRA = Math.max(start.ra, end.ra)
  const maxDec = Math.max(start.ra, end.ra)

  const precision = 10

  const points = getInterpolatedEquatorialCoordinates(start, end, precision)

  const isRAAboveLowerThreshold = (
    p: EquatorialCoordinate
  ) => p.ra >= minRA

  const isRABelowUpperThreshold = (
    p: EquatorialCoordinate
  ) => p.ra <= maxRA

  const isDecAboveLowerThreshold = (
    p: EquatorialCoordinate
  ) => p.dec >= minDec

  const isDecBelowUpperThreshold = (
    p: EquatorialCoordinate
  ) => p.dec <= maxDec

  expect(points.length).toBeGreaterThan(0)
  expect(points.length).toBe(precision)
  expect(points.every(isRAAboveLowerThreshold)).toBe(true)
  expect(points.every(isRABelowUpperThreshold)).toBe(true)
  expect(points.every(isDecAboveLowerThreshold)).toBe(true)
  expect(points.every(isDecBelowUpperThreshold)).toBe(true)
})
```

The interpolated outputted points are as follows:

```js
[
      { ra: 344.4530585, dec: 36.968215199999996 },
      { ra: 344.44081324999996, dec: 38.7681946 },
      { ra: 344.428568, dec: 40.568174 },
      { ra: 344.41632275, dec: 42.3681534 },
      { ra: 344.40407749999997, dec: 44.168132799999995 },
      { ra: 344.39183225, dec: 45.9681122 },
      { ra: 344.379587, dec: 47.7680916 },
      { ra: 344.36734175000004, dec: 49.568071 },
      { ra: 344.3550965, dec: 51.3680504 },
      { ra: 344.34285125, dec: 53.1680298 }
]
```

This seems to work for any precision to a good degree of accuracy that I am happy with, it also works regardless of which "*direction*" we're going.

---

**Question**:

What I want to do now is to apply this to the above `boundaries` array, for every point, returning a new array of all of the points combined as one ...

What would be the best way to achieve this? I've tried using the `Array.prototype.map` method, but to zero success ...

The desired output is as follows for the following "`boundaries"`:

```js
let boundaries = [
    {
      ra: 344.46530375,
      dec: 35.1682358
    },
    {
      ra: 344.34285125,
      dec: 53.1680298
    },
    ...
]

let desiredOutput = [
  {
    ra: 344.46530375,
    dec: 35.1682358
  }, // Original Index 0
  // Start Interpolated Intermediary Values
  { 
    ra: 344.4530585, 
    dec: 36.968215199999996 
  },
  { 
    ra: 344.44081324999996,    
    dec: 38.7681946 
  },
  { 
    ra: 344.428568, 
    dec: 40.568174 
  },
  { 
    ra: 344.41632275, 
    dec: 42.3681534 
  },
  { 
    ra: 344.40407749999997, 
    dec: 44.168132799999995 
  },
  { 
    ra: 344.39183225, 
    dec: 45.9681122 
  },
  { 
    ra: 344.379587, 
    dec: 47.7680916 
  },
  { 
    ra: 344.36734175000004, 
    dec: 49.568071 
  },
  { 
    ra: 344.3550965, 
    dec: 51.3680504 
  },
  { 
    ra: 344.34285125, 
    dec: 53.1680298 
  },
  // End Interpolated Intermediary Values
  {
    ra: 344.34285125,
    dec: 53.1680298
  }, // Original Index 1
  ...
]
```

Comment: If I understand this, your boundaries array has multiple right ascension/declination pairs but your interpolation function expects start and end co-ordinates, each of which represents an ra/dec pair. How do you decide what the start and end pairs should be when invoking the interpolation function? Is it simply adjacent pairs in the boundaries list? So [0,1], then [1,2], then [2,3], up to [N-1,0]?

Comment: @jarmod Exactly that - unfortunately, the IAU simply provide the boundary points as a "continuous" line of points. I understand why you asked this tho, as it might be a random ordered list of points.

Comment: Each invocation of the interpolation function returns an array of P points (where P=precision, 10 in the example). If there are K points in the boundaries array, what does your final, desired output look like? Is it a 1-D array of K*P points?

Comment: Yeh, a 1-D array but of K(1+P) points (original points remain and remain in order - interpolated between). I'll add the desired output to the above question also.

Comment: @Jarmod I've added the desired output. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Good team effort here. I think @shyam and I were both honing in on the eventual solution that Jamie completed first, so props to him.

Comment: Yes, thanks to @shyam and ultimately Jamie here for their combined efforts - I've been circling around the solution for a number of hours but it's been really invaluable to get new sets of eyes on this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Array.reduce() is the best tool to use here.

You could write a function that takes an array of boundaries and a preceistion and outputs your desired array of EquatorialCoordinate:

```
const fillInBoundryPoints = (boundaries: EquatorialCoordinate[], precision: number) => {
  return boundaries.reduce((acc, cur, i, arr) => {
    if (i < arr.length - 1) {
      acc.push(cur)
      acc.push(...getInterpolatedEquatorialCoordinates(cur, arr[i + 1], precision))
    }
    return acc
  }, [] as EquatorialCoordinate[])
}
```

Which you would use as so:

```
const precision = 10

const boundaries: EquatorialCoordinate[] = [
  {
    ra: 344.46530375,
    dec: 35.1682358
  },
  {
    ra: 344.34285125,
    dec: 53.1680298
  }
]

const desiredOutput = fillInBoundryPoints(boundaries, precision)
```

Outputs:

```
[
  { ra: 344.46530375, dec: 35.1682358 },
  { ra: 344.4530585, dec: 36.968215199999996 },
  { ra: 344.44081324999996, dec: 38.7681946 },
  { ra: 344.428568, dec: 40.568174 },
  { ra: 344.41632275, dec: 42.3681534 },
  { ra: 344.40407749999997, dec: 44.168132799999995 },
  { ra: 344.39183225, dec: 45.9681122 },
  { ra: 344.379587, dec: 47.7680916 },
  { ra: 344.36734175000004, dec: 49.568071 },
  { ra: 344.3550965, dec: 51.3680504 },
  { ra: 344.34285125, dec: 53.1680298 }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `map` but, the `reduce` is a more natural fit for this scenario

```js
boundaries.reduce((a,p,i,arr) => {
  if ( i > 0 ) {
    a.push(getInterpolatedEquatorialCoordinates(arr[i-1], p, precision))
  }
  return a;
}, [])
```

**NOTE:**
If you are using the `map` case instead of looking up the previous value you have to lookahead but, you will end up with an `undefined` at the end which you need to slice off

Comment: Hmmmm, this seems to be returning an empty array and a lot of typescript issues as well. I will tag this question as Typescript. Really appreciate your answer nonetheless.

Comment: `getInterpolatedEquatorialCoordinates()` returns an Array as well FYI, so we can't push ...

Comment: You can push an array onto an array, and the accumulator for this is `[]`.

Comment: Yes, of course - technically you can, but then we just get an array inside an array - which is not what the desiredOutput is.

Comment: So just flatten it with `a.push(...getInterpolatedEquatorialCoordinates(arr[i-1], p, precision))`